# Beatport API with node.js/js [general help needed]

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth

Hello there everybody!

I am writing a simple multi-platform app for media tagging. It is written with the help of [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) and it is "almost" ready, the last and most important part is missing - beatport integration.

I have already acquired my self an API Key to work with (played with the [docs](https://oauth-api.beatport.com/)), however I am heavily struggling to wrap my head around the OAuth protocol.

As far as I know I have to go thru the auth process, exchange consumer key and secret, login and receive the real access token - all of this can be done via the docs page and you end up with the access token and secret.

The question is how can I directly use the token and secret with something like [this](https://github.com/Mashape/mashape-oauth#request-methods).

My awful attempt

```
var OAuth = require('mashape-oauth').OAuth;
var oa = new OAuth(method(url, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, body, type, parameters, callback));
var url = "https://oauth-api.beatport.com/catalog/3/search/",
    oauth_token = "MyToken", //obtained directly from the doc page
    oauth_token_secret = "MyTokenSecret", //obtained directly from the doc page
    parameters = "?query=Symphonica&facets=artistName%3ANicky+Romero",
    body = "",
    type = "",
    callback = "";

console.log(oa);
```

Thank you very much any help will be appreciated. If anyone of you who help me, happen to be in prague I'll be very happy to buy you a beer.

(please take in consideration, that this is my first attempt to node/js I come from a php background I like to throw my self in the water even though I can't swim)

Answer (score 2):

It is always about tinkering...

```
var sys = require('sys');
var OAuth = require('oauth').OAuth;
var oa = new OAuth("https://oauth-api.beatport.com/catalog/3/search/",
                  "https://oauth-api.beatport.com/catalog/3/search/",
                  "API KEY","API KEY SECRET",
                  "1.0A", undefined, "HMAC-SHA1");

var url = 'https://oauth-api.beatport.com/catalog/3/search/?query=Symphonica&facets=artistName:Nicky Romero',
    access_token = "Access Token Obtained on doc pages",
    access_token_secret = "Access Token Secret obtained on doc pages";

var request = oa.get(url, access_token, access_token_secret, function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    }
});
```

Changed the node module to [this](https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth) and tinkered with [this example](https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth/wiki/Full-working-example-for-interacting-with-google)

I am going to buy myself a beer :-)